# Installing Wordpress - 404 Error

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded the content of wordpress folder into my httpdocs folder. Its like

httpdocs -> content of wordpress folder

and NOT httpdocs -> wordpress -> content of wordpress folder

I changed the wp-config.php file with the DB user name, password and DB name.

I hit http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/install.php

It throws me a 404 Error while the file is actually in there.

What do you guys think could be causing the problem?

Comment: What did you get if you hit the domain directly? Without `wp-admin/install.php`

Comment: Still a 404 - "The requested document was not found on this server. "

Comment: Try what j0k said. It should take you to the install page if Wordpress is not already installed. Are you on a web host with one click application installs? If so, why not use the installer?

Comment: Im on Plesk. It does not have fantastico or any sich one click installer. So, I uploaded all contents of wordpress folder to httpdocs folder. Now all it throws at me is a 404 error.

Comment: The site is http://realagentindia.com/wp-admin/install.php if that helps.

Comment: If you create a simple html page (call it test.html or something similar) and upload it to the same directory, can you open that in your browser: www.yourdomain.com/test.html ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you fill out MySQL Server Name?
To install a Wordpress you have to fill 4 element :

```
/** MySQL database databasename */
define('DB_NAME', 'databasename');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'MySQL server name');
```

Comment: Yes I have Ida. I have manually created a DB and a user to it. I gave MySQL Server name as localhost.

Comment: I think the problem is in the folder where you put the wordpress installation.
You're being redirected away from the install URL index.php or index.html. Rename .htaccess to htaccess (without the dot) and see if you can install. Or if you know about .htaccess programming, change the value in .htaccess file.
Good Luck !